# Is there a way to read and/or update account options using Microsoft Graph

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

On Office 365 in "Options -> General -> Mobile Devices" there is an option to toggle "Read Receipts" On/Off for devices that use Exchange ActiveSync. Is this available thru Graph?

The beta (or v1.0) metadata url didn't point to anything obvious:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't available through Graph. If your mailbox is configured for them, emails send through Graph will apply them, but it isn't possible to *enable* this functionality through the Graph.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Marc! Do you know if it's available through EWS?

Comment: I seem to recall doing this with EWS once, but it might have been using the PowerShell cmdlets. To be completely transparent, it has been a _long_ time since I've worked with either of those so I could be completely off base however.